# EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on production app, It's happening for 5% users but I am unable to reproduce it

Tags: ios, swift

Retain cycle just cause memory leak or it can also cause BAD_ACCESS at some point?

My app is crashing on prod sometimes, I could not reproduce the crash while debugging. I am guessing the crash is due to concurrency, but at same I have found a retain cycle but I think it can not cause crash, it can just leak.

Can anyone guess exact problem from below crash logs:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000009f34b81e0

0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1a2f3738c objc_release + 28
    1  TTTApp                          0x1018cdfbc TTTUser.__deallocating_deinit + 13 (TTTUser.swift:13)
    2  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b0b2cbd4 _swift_release_dealloc + 36
    3  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b0b2ba3c swift_release + 32
    4  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b0b224c4 swift_arrayDestroy + 84
    5  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b08bc99c _ContiguousArrayStorage.__deallocating_deinit + 48
    6  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b0b2cbd4 _swift_release_dealloc + 36
    7  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b0b2ba3c swift_release + 32
    8  TTTApp                          0x1018e0768 TTTChannel.deinit + 13 (TTTChannel.swift:13)
    9  TTTApp                          0x1018e07c4 TTTChannel.__deallocating_deinit + 13 (TTTChannel.swift:13)
    10 libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b0b2cbd4 _swift_release_dealloc + 36
    11 libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b0b2d754 bool swift::RefCounts<swift::SideTableRefCountBits>::doDecrement<(swift::PerformDeinit)1>(unsigned int) + 248
    12 libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b0b2ba3c swift_release + 32
    13 TTTApp                          0x1018d28e4 TTTContaxt.__deallocating_deinit + 13 (TTTContaxt.swift:13)
    14 libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b0b2cbd4 _swift_release_dealloc + 36
    15 libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b0b2ba3c swift_release + 32
    16 TTTApp                          0x102495e04 protocol witness for TTTContaxtProtocol.getWidgetViews(context:) in conformance TTTCustomojiContaxt + 54 (Customoji.swift:54)
    17 TTTApp                          0x101a0c598 TTTInputDriver.setupWidgetAccessoryView(_:) + 256 (TTTInputDriver.swift:256)
    18 TTTApp                          0x101a0cea0 TTTInputDriver.onTTTContaxtUpdated(context:) + 285 (TTTInputDriver.swift:285)
    19 TTTApp                          0x101a231f8 TTTViewController.onTTTContaxtUpdated(context:) + 190 (TTTViewController.swift:190)
    20 TTTApp                          0x101a28ba4 closure #1 in TTTViewControllerPresenter.contextDidUpdate(context:completion:) + 51 (TTTViewControllerPresenter.swift:51)
    21 TTTApp                          0x1001e4a3c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4339206716 (<compiler-generated>:4339206716)
    22 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a2ea8b7c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    23 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a2ea9fd8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    24 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a2eb5cc8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 968
    25 CoreFoundation                 0x1a317fcc8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
    26 CoreFoundation                 0x1a317aa24 __CFRunLoopRun + 1980
    27 CoreFoundation                 0x1a3179f40 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
    28 GraphicsServices               0x1ad3f7534 GSEventRunModal + 108
    29 UIKitCore                      0x1a72f2a60 UIApplicationMain + 1940
    30 TTTApp                          0x1001b22ec main + 41 (VTTTTAppCreator.swift:41)
    31 libdyld.dylib                  0x1a2ff8e18 start + 4
```

Comment: if you are not using Crashlytics or something similar i recommend to do so....

Comment: Implement crashlytics to get a proper detail of the crash

Comment: the logs are from crashlytics

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS indicated a dangling pointer error. Somewhere there is a deallocated object that is still referenced and you tried to dereference it, hence the error. This could be found in a retain cycle setting where you try to force unwrap a weak parent that is deallocated.